# Unable to do anything with conda

Tags: ubuntu, conda

I installed conda following this [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04).
Now, when I tried to install any package or create virtual environment or to check for available python versions, I was not able to do.
To do anything with conda, I am getting the following error message.

```
Fetching package metadata ...Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Conda Info:

```
Current conda install:

           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : 3.0.27
     python version : 3.6.3.final.0
   requests version : 2.18.4
   root environment : /root/anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : /root/anaconda3
   envs directories : /root/anaconda3/envs
                      /root/.conda/envs
      package cache : /root/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /root/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : None
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Linux/4.19.81-nn8-server debian/stretch/sid glibc/2.23    
            UID:GID : 0:0
```

I tried with latest version of anaconda.

```
    (base) root@nsx-rasa:/home/code# conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /root/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /root/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /root/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /root/anaconda3/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Linux/4.19.81-nn8-server ubuntu/16.04.2 glibc/2.23
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

But still I am getting an error. But this time, error is

```
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
CondaMemoryError: The conda process ran out of memory. Increase system memory and/or try again.
```

Comment: Why is the conda installation in `/root`? Is that a directory you chose specifically? Also you have installed a rather outdated version of `anaconda`, please try [the latest one](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh)

Comment: Looks like your system is running out of memory. What is your system setup (hard and software)?